# Notifications not displayed when app is in foreground and onMessageReceived is called

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-notifications

I am trying to display a notification when the fcm message received and the APP is in the background. I tried different flavors of notifications but not luck. The notification won't show

Here is the code

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(GlobalVar.TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);


        String channelId = getString(R.string.notification_channel_id);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()).setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        manager.notify(0, builder.build());

    }
```

I know this is getting called because I get the log.
If the app is in the background then FCM displays notifications. It is the above code that is not displaying it when app is in foreground
Any suggestions?

PS: I created the channel in the Application class

I don't get errors in the log cat. I am also setting all the notifications settings as per code below. Please note my device receive and display notifications already from FCM when it is in background. But when it is in foreground and "I" handle the display of notification then it does not work

Comment: provide your manifest

Comment: Check If that application is allowed notifications in settings

Comment: And it also depends on how you create NotificationChannel. Try to create NotificationChannel with `IMPORTANCE_HIGH` in your code. In some devices, if your notification channel's priority is not high, it won't show the notification.

Comment: In implementation of FCM. you can not show notification in background until you didn't modify the JSON coming from FCM . You need to modify JSON from notification tag to data tag.

Comment: https://medium.com/@piyush052/receive-push-notifications-simply-in-android-6433cdd5dbb6
check this link.

Comment: Guys, your comments are checking if  I am sending the data correctly from the server. This is not the issue. It is correct because I am receiving the message on the device and I am able to obtain data. The issue is with the display of the notification when I try to call the notification system from withing the FirbaseService. Something seems to be blocking the notification fro being displayed

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully your server is sending you notification in `data` key.

Here as I saw your code, You are getting notification data using **`remoteMessage.getNotification()`**

Now you have to make changes in your server side script that they send in `data` key as follow **([You can test temporary before changing server code](https://medium.com/android-school/test-fcm-notification-with-postman-f91ba08aacc3))**:

```
{
 "to" : "YOUR_FCM_TOKEN_WILL_BE_HERE",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "data" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification in Data",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification in Title",
     "key_1" : "Value for key_1",
     "key_2" : "Value for key_2"
 }
}
```

and after that you can receive like this:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }
}
```

To know more about it:

[image]

Hope you will get help in this. Do let me know if you get any problem.

Comment: try not to post some random code here . I mean what is `NotificationBean`? Where is `#sendNotification()`?

Comment: @ADM Yeah, let me change.

Comment: Thanks but as I said in the question. The onMessageReceive is called so I know I am getting call from FCM. Also notification is already working when the app is in the background and handled through FCM. My issue is that when the app is in forground and "I" create notification, then it is not shown

Answer (score -4):

If you're not using your own server, then you can't achieve this. You need to use your own server to modify the JSON format from this:

```
{
 "to" : "YOUR_FCM_TOKEN_WILL_BE_HERE",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification in Data",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification in Title",
     "key_1" : "Value for key_1",
     "key_2" : "Value for key_2"
 }
}
```

to:

```
{
 "to" : "YOUR_FCM_TOKEN_WILL_BE_HERE",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "data" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification in Data",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification in Title",
     "key_1" : "Value for key_1",
     "key_2" : "Value for key_2"
 }
}
```

when your server will modify "notification" tag with "data" then only you can recieve notification in background.